# The type org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver is not accessible error

Tags: selenium

I am getting the following error :- The type org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver is not accessible

code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

}
```

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\pathto\\my\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

**EDIT**

WebDriver is the interface that classes like ChromeDriver, FirefoxDriver, etc. should implement, this interface has all the methods that will use in the future.

May be help this article:
https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/webdriver-driver-new-firefoxdriver/

Comment: Could you explain your code and why it will solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @SiKing